# Jordan forms for linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reviewing linear algebra and came across the following problem in Artin:

The characteristic polynomial for a linear operator $T$ is $(t-\lambda)^5$. And the rank  of $(T-\lambda I)$ is 2. What are the Jordan forms of T? (Assume the dimension of vector space is 5)

I am really stuck at this problem as I have no idea how to proceed without having the actual matrix at hand. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: A small correction: you don't need to "assume" the dimensio nof the vector space is $5$: once you say the degree of the characteristic polynomial is $5$, you already know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you some hints to get you started. Feel free to ask for more clarification if you need it.

What can you say about the nullity of the matrix if the rank is $2$? So what is the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace? How many Jordan blocks must there then be?

Comment: If the rank is 2 then the nullity will be of order 3 and so will be the dimension of the eigenspace. Hence, there will be 3 Jordan blocks. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So given that you have exactly three Jordan blocks, what are the possible Jordan forms? There should be two distinct Jordan forms.

Comment: Well, we need to have$\lambda$ appear on the diagonals 5 times. So, one block has to be 1x1 and two other will be 2x2. However, I am still not sure where the entry "1" will go in this case.

Comment: Well, you already know you need three blocks. You also know that the three blocks together make up a $5\times 5$ matrix. There are two possibilities in this case. Either the blocks have sizes $3$, $1$ and $1$ or the blocks have sizes $2$, $2$ and $1$.

Comment: The "1" entries are what groups your $\lambda$s together as a single block. For example $$\begin{pmatrix}\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix},\ \ \begin{pmatrix}\lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix}$$ The matrix on the left has two blocks of size $1$. The one on the right has one block of size $2$. The presence of the "1" is what groups the $\lambda$s together as a single block.

Comment: Can you please expand further on the position of "1" So, if I understand this right, if you ve a 3x3 block then the "1" would be above the second and third diagonal entry?

Comment: Right. Say we have a $3\times 3$ Jordan form with a single eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then there are several possibilities as to what the form looks like (up to ordering of the blocks): $$\begin{pmatrix}\lambda & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix},\ \ \begin{pmatrix}\lambda & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix},\ \ \begin{pmatrix}\lambda & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix}$$ The matrix on the left has three blocks of size $1$. The middle matrix has two blocks, of size $2$ and $1$. The one on the right has a single block of size $3$.

Comment: In a given Jordan block, all the entries of the superdiagonal are populated with $1$s. If there is a break, that means you have moved to another block. For example $$\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix}$$ The matrix above has two Jordan blocks. This is indicated by the missing $1$ above the third $\lambda$. If you instead want one whole block, you would write $$\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix}$$ with no break on the superdiagonal.